# Loading a xml to a class with Javascript

Tags: javascript, xml

How can I load a XML file to class using Javascript?

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately, each browser presents its own way of parsing a string containing XML.  Here are the ways that I know of for each of the big 3 browsers.  Please note, I haven't had a chance to try each of these as they're cobbled together from various blogs and my own memory.

Firefox has an object called `DOMParser` that can be used to parse XML in a string.  The API is pretty simple -- instantiate the `DOMParser` and call its `parseFromString` method.   Here is an example:

```
var xmlString = '<?xml version="1.0"?>...';
var parser = new DOMParser();
var dom = parser.parseFromString(theString, "text/xml");
// use dom
```

IE uses the Microsoft ActiveX XMLDOM control, therefore you must instantiate the DOM control and use its methods, again here's an example:

```
var xmlString = '<?xml version="1.0"?>...';
dom=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
dom.async="false";
dom.loadXML(xmlString);
// use dom
```

And lastly, the weirdo Safari version.  Safari doesn't have a parser built in, and being that it doesn't run on Windows it doesn't support ActiveX controls.  However, Safari does support `data:` urls.  In Safari a URL with the document is created and called through an XMLHTTPRequest.  Like all XMLHttpRequests, you use the standard `responseXml` property of the XMLHttpRequest to access the DOM.

```
var xmlString = '<?xml version="1.0"?>...';
var url = "data:text/xml;charset=utf-8," + encodeURIComponent(xmlString);

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", url, false);
xhr.send(null);

var dom = xhr.responseXML;
// Use dom here
```

Comment: Actually Safari runs on Windows, but that of course doesn't change the fact that it's unable to use ActiveX. +1.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of a built-in XML serializer/deserializer in JavaScript.  Is you considered something native to JavaScript, like JSON?

Comment: And JSON can be dynamically loaded?

Comment: Yes, JSON can be loaded dynamically.  See jQuery's getJSON method at http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.getJSON

Answer (score 0):

Here is an [XML to JSON Javascript converter](http://www.thomasfrank.se/xml_to_json.html) that might steer you in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks for the link. How can I load JSON in a class?

Answer (score 0):

This code will work for all kind of browsers

```
var url="file.xml"
var xmlDoc="";
if(window.XMLHttpRequest&&!window.ActiveXObject)
{
    var Gz=new XMLHttpRequest();Gz.open('GET',url,false);Gz.send(null);xmlDoc=Gz.responseXML;
}
else
{
    xmlDoc=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");xmlDoc.async=false;xmlDoc.load(url);
}
```

After using this, you can parse the tag and retrieve the data.